# Custom Form Input not saving to Database

Tags: customization, database

I have created a custom form using shortcode widget for my page sidebar, but the form input wasn't saving to may wordpress database. 
Can anyone help me with this. Please see below my codes.

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ){

    global $wpdb;
   $lplifeinsurance_leads=$wpdb->prefix.'lplifeinsurance';

    $data=array(
        'quotes' => $_POST['quotes'], 
        'cover' => $_POST['cover'],
        'health' => $_POST['health'], 
        'provider' => $_POST['provider'],
        'birthdate' => $_POST['birthdate'],
        'gender' => $_POST['gender'], 
        'lname' => $_POST['lname'], 
        'address' => $_POST['address'],
        'number' => $_POST['number'], 
        'email' => $_POST['email'] );


     $wpdb->insert( $lplifeinsurance_leads, $data);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert('$lplifeinsurance_leads',$data,array('%s','%s'));
```

Comment: Please explain that code snippet.